# JQuery - creating multiple divs with event handler and altering child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have defined an event handler within jquery that when a button on an HTML page is clicked, a new `div` is created and assign it an `id` of an integer (integer increases with every new `div` made).

Within that `div`, I add a list of paragraph elements.  I also an input field and additional button that changes adds a new paragraph within that `div`.

What I'm having trouble with is how to define the function that adds the new paragraph within each div.  The callback function has exactly the same structure but uses a different `id`.

Within my code, I have only managed to defined the event handler for the first `<div>` I create with `id='0'`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3aYdM/

As a side note, my project is part of a Google drive real-time API that uses JavaScript.  I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: The JSFiddle is not complete. If you provide the missing parts you'll have a better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Whenever I click the 'add task' button, a new task is displayed on the page in a div.  Within that div, an option to add an update is provided with the 'add update' button.  What I have trouble with is writing the code for each 'add update' button

Answer (score 0):

You can add live event handlers to any kind of elements. These handlers will support current elements and future, too.

```
 $('ul').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
      console.log($(this).text());
      $(this).parent().append('<li>Test ' + ($(this).parent().find('li').length + 1) + '</li>');
 });
```

This code will attach event handlers to all current li's and future ones :)

Hope this helps!